# Creating CollectionView Programmatically with Swift 4

Tags: swift, collections, tableview, swift4

I know similar questions have been asked, but I have not found how to create a collectionView inside a tableViewCell programatically. I want to be able to create a variable number of collection views inside my tableViewCell (without having to create them from the storyboard).

Right now I have a tableViewController, tableViewCell, and collectionViewCell.

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: First you need to create a UICollectionViewLayout or a subclass.  The best one to start with is a UICollectionViewFlowLayout unless you want to build your own.  Then you can create a UICollectionView based on that layout using something like `var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)` using your layout and a frame.

Comment: Would this be created in the cell class?

Comment: If you want the collection view inside the table view cell then yes.

Comment: I added this to the cell class, and used a UICollectionViewLayout instead of a UICOllectionViewFlowLayout and I was able to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: No worries glad to point you in the right direction